# Are mail redirect not reliable?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record, gmail, redirection

I have now twice created a setup on two different platforms which appear to fail - sometimes. The emails just appear to vanish.

I have a domain name and configured a MX record on the DNS to send emails to a mail hotel which support mail alias/redirection. The alias redirect the mail to one or more email addresses on other domains - except when I send emails (from Gmail) and the email are redirected back to the same hosting company (Google) the email sometimes appear to just disappear.

To visualize the mail goes like this: xxx@example.com (sender) -> yyy@example.net (alias/redirect) -> zzz@example.com (receiver)

I am surprised that email redirection appear to be so fragile. Is there anything I can do to make it stable?

Comment: Check your log files for what what happens exactly on the server doing the forwarding and check the Spam folder belonging to the final recipient, as possibly the server doing the forwarding isn't configured correctly. But most likely anti-spam  filters decide that your intermediate example.net mailserver isn't authorised to send mail from the original sender, the example.com domain.

Comment: @HBruijn There are nothing in the spam folders and I am trying to get log entries at the forwarding site. It is the second site I experience this problem. This setup must be so common that a lot of people are hit by it so I thought there must be something wrong - but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Looks like a problem with SPF: the MX for the example.com domain considers that the redirecting server is not allowed to send emails for the example.com domain… The only solutions might be to convince the administrators of the example.com domain to stop using SPF, or to rewrite the envelope sender in the redirecting server (look for SRS, sender rewriting scheme).

Comment: @user2233709 As example.com being Google Gmail.com in this case I pretty sure I am out of luck! so yeah I may need to find a way to rewrite the envelope on the example.net server - but that must be a problem for a lot of people or are redirects just not done anymore?